# SQL XML nested query

Tags: sql, xml, nested

How to generate below like XML based on such query?

```
SELECT
    t1.Code,    
    (SELECT
        CASE 
            WHEN t1.Type = 5 THEN
                (SELECT top 1
                    t2.CodeName
                FROM dbo.Table2 t2
                WHERE t2.Id = t4.Id
          FOR XML  PATH('Code'), TYPE)          
      ELSE  
          (SELECT 
             t3.CodeName
          FROM dbo.Table3 t3
                WHERE t3.Id = t4.Id
                FOR XML PATH('Code'), TYPE)                     
      END
    FROM dbo.Table4 t4
    WHERE t4.Id = t1.Id
    FOR XML PATH('CodeNames'), TYPE)    
FROM dbo.Table1  t1 WITH (NOLOCK)
FOR XML RAW ('Table1Child'), TYPE, ROOT('Table1Root')
```

Expected output

```
<Table1Root>
  <Table1Child Code="ABC">
    <CodeNames>
      <Code Name="A1" />
      <Code Name="B2" />
      <Code Name="C3" />
    </CodeNames>
  </Table1Child>
  <Table1Child Code="DEF">
    <CodeNames>
      <Code Name="D4" />
      <Code Name="E5" />
      <Code Name="F6" />
    </CodeNames>
  </Table1Child>
</Table1Root>
```

Comment: <Table1Root>
  <Table1Child Code="ABC">
    <CodeNames>
      <Code Name="A1" />
      <Code Name="B2" />
      <Code Name="C3" />
    </CodeNames>
  </Table1Child>
  <Table1Child Code="DEF">
    <CodeNames>
      <Code Name="D4" />
      <Code Name="E5" />
      <Code Name="F6" />
    </CodeNames>
  </Table1Child>
</Table1Root>

Comment: please **do not** put code or XML into comments - it's **REALLY** hard to read!! Instead: update your original question by editing it, and provide that additional info. In your question, you can properly format your XML and get nice syntax highlighting, too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a `UNION` instead of `CASE` and use `@` to create an attribute.

```
SELECT
    t1.Code,    
    (SELECT
      (SELECT CodeName as '@Name'
       FROM (
             SELECT t2.CodeName
             FROM Table2 t2
             WHERE t2.Id = t4.Id AND
                   t1.Type = 5
             UNION ALL
             SELECT t3.CodeName
             FROM Table3 t3
             WHERE t3.Id = t4.Id AND
                   t1.Type <> 5
            ) AS T 
       FOR XML PATH('Code'), TYPE)          
     FROM Table4 t4
     WHERE t4.Id = t1.Id
     FOR XML PATH('CodeNames'), TYPE)    
FROM Table1 t1
FOR XML RAW ('Table1Child'), TYPE, ROOT('Table1Root')
```

It looks like you actually don't need to use `Table4`.

```
SELECT
    t1.Code,    
      (SELECT CodeName as '@Name'
       FROM (
             SELECT t2.CodeName
             FROM Table2 t2
             WHERE t2.Id = t1.Id AND
                   t1.Type = 5
             UNION ALL
             SELECT t3.CodeName
             FROM Table3 t3
             WHERE t3.Id = t1.Id AND
                   t1.Type <> 5
            ) AS T 
       FOR XML PATH('Code'), ROOT('CodeNames'), TYPE)          
FROM Table1 t1
FOR XML RAW ('Table1Child'), TYPE, ROOT('Table1Root')
```

Comment: Thanks Mikael! This looks pretty neat, but I CASE is good for certain performnce issues as I'm doing some cross database lookups...